# Grails - different passwords for same salt in Spring Security

Tags: grails, spring-security, passwords, salt

My web app is using Spring Security plugin for authentication and authorization. I'm building sort of an API, where I need to verify user password.

Spring Security is configured to use BCrypt with 5 logrounds and `username` property as salt:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.password.algorithm = 'brcypt' 
grails.plugins.springsecurity.password.bcrypt.logrounds = 5
grails.plugins.springsecurity.dao.reflectionSaltSourceProperty = 'username' // password salting
```

Now, in my controller I'd like to verify user password and login. For this, I call `springSecurityService.encodePassword(cmd.password, cmd.username)`

where `cmd` is command object with my params. The thing is, on each request, password encoded with `springSecurityService` is different and never the  same as user password in databse. I tried also with constant values in `encodePassword` call, something like this:
`springSecurityService.encodePassword('foo', 'bar')` and result is the same: on each request encoded password is different. This way I can't verify user password and get valid user instance from databse.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 6):

`bcrypt` generates a uniq salt each time, and includes it into result hash. Because of it `springSecurityService.encodePasswod` just ignores second argument, and `reflectionSaltSourceProperty` option as well ([see sources](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/src/java/grails/plugins/springsecurity/BCryptPasswordEncoder.java)). So, each time you'll get different hash for same input data.

You can use `BCrypt` class to validate password, like:

```
if (BCrypt.checkpw(candidate_password, stored_hash))
    System.out.println("It matches");
else
    System.out.println("It does not match");
```

See docs for BCrypt: http://static.springsource.org/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCrypt.html

Btw, as you're using Spring Security, it's already implemented in framework, so you can use `passwordEncoder` bean:

```
def passwrodEncoder
...
passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(user.password, cmd.password, user.username) //user.username will be ignored
```

Comment: thank you. If doing password checks explicitly in your own code in conjunction with using spring security core plugin, and if having not overridden the password hashing encoder, this is essential information. BCrypt, the default in the plugin, does not take an external salt even though the docs encourage the user to do so.